# Php echo " and '

Tags: php, echo

Can someone help me with this code, I know what I'm doing wrong but I don't know how to repair it.

```
echo "<div onclick='showplayer('".$usersList["username"]."')' id='playerLookupNameResult' style='color:".$color.";'>Some text</div>
```

I need to use " after onclick= but it is already used after echo.

Comment: You're generating JavaScript and HTML. You aren't escaping either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can escape `"` like this `\"`.

```
echo "<div onclick=\"'showplayer('".$usersList["username"]."')'\" id='playerLookupNameResult' style='color:".$color.";'>Some text</div>
```